# Azure Data Factory: How does export of U-SQL variables to next box in a pipeline work?

Tags: u-sql, azure-data-factory

I have a Pipeline in my Azure Data Factory with a,

U-SQL --> ForEach --> Web

..flow setup.

My U-SQL will eventually do a "select" of a single column and I want to call an API for each of the selected rows in the single column.

Can I do this like that?

If yes, How do I get the variable holding the selected query output in the U-SQL script out to the Azure Data Factory?

(so the ForEach can pick it up as a list and send each entry to the Web box, which calls the API and gets the data I need)

---

Right now, my alternative is to take a U-SQL box that selects the column and exports it to /Temp on ADLS and then have one big Azure Batch C# box that read the file and manually for loops the lines and runs the API call for each line. I am just hoping there would be a prettier way more modular ADF style way of doing the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U-SQL scripts do not return data, so you are on the right path. Azure Batch adds another layer of complexity that you probably don't need in this case. An ADF [Lookup Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity) can read Blob Storage and ADLS Gen 1, so your pipeline could do the following:

1. U-SQL Activity outputs column to blob.
2. Lookup Activity reads blob.
3. Foreach Activity loops through Lookup results.
4. -> internal Web Activity calls API.

Comment: It works Joel, but ultimately I had to go full Batch/Exe due to complications with the API. Had it been a simple API that the Web box could handle it would have worked so marking as answer.
I understand the limitations of the ADF flows better now.